# Rewrite getLargest to recursive method in Java

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, max

I am doing this assignment and I am having trouble writing this method recursively.
I have this way to do it which is effective but not recursive:

```
public static <T extends Comparable< ? super T>> T getLargest(T [] a, int low, 
              int high)
{
    if(low>high)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    return Collections.max(Arrays.asList(Arrays.copyOfRange(a, low, high)));
```

So from there I went to this one, which kind of extends it but is not recursive either:

```
T[] arrCopy = (T[]) new Object[high-low];
    for(int i=low;i<high;i++){
        if(a[i].compareTo(a[i-1])>0)
            arrCopy[i]=a[i];
        else
            arrCopy[i]=a[i+1];
    }
    return arrCopy[0];
```

And I've been working on it for hours and can't seem a way to make it recursive and make it work.
Any help and ideas are greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is a very bad candidate for recursion.  You're not going to get better than `O(n)` comparisons so you're not dividing and conquering; you're using recursion for absolutely no reason.

Comment: Also avoid using generic arrays at all costs.  They are asking for a headache.  Accept a `List<T>` instead of a `T[]`.

Comment: Well one can easily implement this recursive, but since JVMs don't do tail recursion (?) it's a bad idea. Also please first fix your iterative version - why in god's name are you allocating an array for getLargest?! If you have a sensible iterative version, it should be obvious how to proceed.

Comment: @Mark: Thanks for your responde, I know is not the best example for recursion. I am just getting examples to study for my exam. It is not about getting better timing than O(n). But to practice for recursion from examples given in class. If timing and effectiveness was an issue, I would use the first code I had.

Comment: @Voo Well the idea is to check for the first element and compare it to the next one and then call the method again to check for the next one, and so on. From when I wrote it in paper to get organized it could be done in a few lines but for some reason I can't make it work right.

Comment: If you want to practice recursion, try the fibonacci sequence, or dealing with binary trees, for example.  you could also parse an xml file that may have the same element as a sub-element (so an organization node may contain organization nodes).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the right answer:

```
T tmp = a[low];
    for(int i=0;i<=high;i++){
        if(a[i].compareTo(tmp)>0){
            tmp = a[i];
            getLargest(a,i,high);               
        }
    }
    return tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here is a template for turning a for-loop into a tail-recursive method:

```
//iterative version
public Object getIteratively(Object[] a) {
   Object retVal = null;
   for (int i = 0; i < a.length; a++ ) {
      //do something
   }
   return retVal;
}

//recursive version
public Object getRecursively(Object[] a) {
    doGetRecursively(a, 0, null);
}

private Object doGetRecursively(Object[] a, int i, Object retVal) {
   if ( i == a.length ) {
      return retVal;
   }
   //do something
   return doGetRecursively(a, i+1, retVal);
}
```

Why you would ever want to do this in a non-functional language is beyond me though.

In this case `//do something` would be the same in both cases, e.g.:

```
if ( a[i].compareTo(retVal) > 0 ) {
   retVal = a[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, your method signature is incorrect. You do not need a 'low'. You should take an array/list as input and return the largest element. You may find however that you want a secondary method that requires extra arguments.

When approaching recursion and you're stuck, it's often best to identify your base case(s) first, then deal with your recursive case(s) next.

Your base case is the simplest case in which you know the answer. In this problem, you know what the largest element is right away if the size of your list is 1 - you just return the only element. You may want to think about the case where your list is empty as well.

Your recursive case then, is whenever your list has size greater than 1. In your recursive case, you want to try and 'break a piece off' and then send the rest to a recursive call. In this case, you can look at the first element in the list, and compare it to the result you get from a recursive call on the rest of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Okay before this gets out of hand, here's a simple iterative and the equivalent recursive solution to this - implemented with ints though so you have to change it a bit ;)

```
public static int getLargest(int[] vals) {
    int max = vals[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < vals.length; i++) {
        max = Math.max(max, vals[i]);
    }
    return max;
}

public static int getLargestRec(int[] vals) {
    return getLargestRec(vals, 0, vals.length);
}

private static int getLargestRec(int[] vals, int low, int high) {
    if (low + 1 == high) {
        return vals[low];
    }
    int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
    int left = getLargestRec(vals, low, middle);
    int right = getLargestRec(vals, middle, high);
    return Math.max(left, right);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] vals = {5, 23, 32, -5, 4, 6};
    System.out.println(getLargestRec(vals));
    System.out.println(getLargest(vals));
}
```

Note that as usual for recursive problems the lower bound is inclusive and the higher bound is exclusive. Also we could implement this differently as well, but the usual divide & conquer approach is rather useful and lends itself nicely to parallelization with a fork framework, so that's fine. (And yes for an empty array both versions will fail)